# DataTable row indexes do no match the order when bound to Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, session-variables

I have a Gridview with different items, ordered by the integer column "Order". I am saving the DataTable that feeds the Gridview as "Session Parameter".

```
Item        Order      LinkButtons
----------------------------------
Item1         1         up   down
Item2         2         up   down
Item3         3         up   down
```

The idea is to customize the order of the items by moving them up and down with the LinkButtons.

This is what I do:

- I get the row index from the RowClick Event

  ```
  LinkButton lb = (sender as LinkButton);
  string OrderNr = lb.CommandArgument;
  int OrderNummer = Convert.ToInt16(OrderNr);
  GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)lb.NamingContainer;
  int idx = row.RowIndex;
  ```
- Call the Session table and change the Order Parameter

  ```
  DataTable t = Session["SessionData"] as DataTable;
  t.Rows[idx][1] = Convert.ToString(OrderNummer - 1);
  t.Rows[idx-1][1] = Convert.ToString(OrderNummer);
  ```
- I then reorder the DataTable and bind it back to the Grid

  ```
  t.DefaultView.Sort = "OderNr";
  t = t.DefaultView.ToTable();
  ```

This unfortunately works only on the first Operation. Afterwards what is returned from t.Rows[idx] is unpredictable to me as the Gridrow Row Index doesn't match the DataTable Row index.

Very confusing

---

Finally my solution was avoiding the row indexes and identifying the DataTable row in a loop using the CommandArgument "OrderNumber".

```
    protected void SelectOrderUp(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["SessionData"] != null)
        {
            LinkButton lb = (sender as LinkButton);
            string OrderNr = lb.CommandArgument;
            int OrderNummer = Convert.ToInt16(OrderNr);

            DataTable t = Session["SessionData"] as DataTable;
            DataRow[] rows = t.Select();

            for (int i = 0; i < rows.Length; i++)
            {
                if (Convert.ToInt16(rows[i][7].ToString()) == OrderNummer)
                {
                    rows[i][7] = Convert.ToString(OrderNummer-1);
                    rows[i - 1][7] = OrderNummer;
                    break;
                }
            }

            t.DefaultView.Sort = "OrderNummer";
            t = t.DefaultView.ToTable();
            Session["SessionData"] = t;

            GridView_Criteria.DataSource = t;
            GridView_Criteria.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does you Grid View have an edit row where you add new rows?  You may be sorting the blank edit row which would explain the issue.

Comment: No, no edit mode in the Grid.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that you using "default" view for the grid binding.

But default view DOES NOT change the row index of the base table!!!

This results in 2 possible solutions:

You consider using dataitem index from the GridView, and NOT row index.

Or, simpler is to sort the base table.

You can do this with this:

```
        rstData.DefaultView.Sort = "MyOrder";
        rstData = rstData.DefaultView.ToTable();
        Session["rstData"] = rstData;
```

Note VERY close in above, we have to shove the rstData table BACK into session[], since we have re-built the table with .ToTable(), and that in effect is a new instance of the object.

So, here is a working example (I have included the MyOrder column in this example). Also keep in mind, that rows are 0 based, and your example started with 1. For this example, "MyOrder" column starts at 0, and not one.

So, say this markup:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GVHotels" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    DataKeyNames="ID" CssClass="table" 
    Width="45%" >
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="HotelName" HeaderText="HotelName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="MyOrder" HeaderText="Order" />
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="cmdUp" runat="server" Text="UP"
                    OnClick="cmdUp_Click" CssClass="btn" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="cmdDown" runat="server" Text="Down"
                    OnClick="cmdDown_Click" CssClass="btn" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

And code behind:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            string strSQL = @"SELECT * FROM tblHotelsA
                        WHERE Active = 1";

            rstData = General.MyRst(strSQL);
            LoadGrid();
        }
        else
            rstData = (DataTable)Session["rstData"];
    }

    void LoadGrid()
    {
        rstData.DefaultView.Sort = "MyOrder";
        rstData = rstData.DefaultView.ToTable();
        Session["rstData"] = rstData;
        GVHotels.DataSource = rstData;
        GVHotels.DataBind();

    }

    protected void cmdUp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button btn = (Button)sender;
        GridViewRow gRow = (GridViewRow)btn.NamingContainer;
        int IX = gRow.RowIndex;            
        if (IX > 0)
        {
            rstData.Rows[IX]["MyOrder"] = IX - 1;
            rstData.Rows[IX - 1]["MyOrder"] = IX;
            LoadGrid();
        }
    }

    protected void cmdDown_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button btn = (Button)sender;
        GridViewRow gRow = (GridViewRow)btn.NamingContainer;
        int IX = gRow.RowIndex;
        if (IX < rstData.Rows.Count - 1)
        {
            rstData.Rows[IX]["MyOrder"] = IX + 1;
            rstData.Rows[IX + 1]["MyOrder"] = IX;
            LoadGrid();
        }
    }
```

The result is this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, Albert! Great explanation of the issue that was driving me nuts.

Answer (score 1):

Not influent in C#, code may need optimization/fine-tuning.

**aspx**

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="false">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="Btn_UP" runat="server" Text="UP" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Order") %>' OnCommand="Btn_UP_Command"></asp:LinkButton>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="Btn_DN" runat="server" Text="Down" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Order") %>' OnCommand="Btn_DN_Command"></asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

**Page_Load**

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    GridView1.DataSource = Get_DataTable();
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

**Get_DataTable**

```
public DataTable Get_DataTable()
{
    if (Session["dt"] == null)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Item", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("Order", typeof(int));
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
            dt.Rows.Add($"Item {i}", i);
        return dt;
    }
    else
        return (DataTable)Session["dt"];
}
```

**Btn_UP_Command**

```
DataTable dt = Get_DataTable();
int order = int.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
if (order == 1)
    return;
dt.Select($"Order={order}")[0]["Order"] = -1;
dt.Select($"Order={order - 1}")[0]["Order"] = order;
dt.Select("Order=-1")[0]["Order"] = order - 1;
dt.DefaultView.Sort = "Order";
Session["dt"] = dt.DefaultView.ToTable();
GridView1.DataSource = dt;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

**Btn_DN_Command**

```
DataTable dt = Get_DataTable();
int order = int.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
if (order == dt.Rows.Count)
    return;
dt.Select($"Order={order}")[0]["Order"] = -1;
dt.Select($"Order={order + 1}")[0]["Order"] = order;
dt.Select("Order=-1")[0]["Order"] = order + 1;
dt.DefaultView.Sort = "Order";
Session["dt"] = dt.DefaultView.ToTable();
GridView1.DataSource = dt;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: Thank you Shahram, that works great! I am not familiar with the syntax of the DataTable operations so I might consider Albert's solution. Could you help me even with the syntax of the dt.Select operation. I need to filter those dt lines that do not have a value for the "order" column. Not all records can be ordered